# How to pass value that's being fetched asynchronously to a component's Input in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to pass a value to a component's input

`<my-comp  [question]="currentQuestion"></my-comp>`

but the variable `currentQuestion` is being fetched asynchronously at the point the page first loads so understandably I get an `undefined` error. How can I get around this?

template of my-comp

```
<div>
  <p>{{question.title}}</p>
</div>
```

class of my-comp

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-comp",
  templateUrl: "./my-comp.html"
})
export class MyComp {
  @Input() question: any;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Elvis` operator `?.` inside interpolation in your child component `my-comp`.

```
{{ currentQuestion?.aField }}
```

In case `currentQuestion` is falsy (undefined, null, etc.) it won't access `aField` member.

`currentQuestion` will be undefined until you get response from asynchronous call.

**Update**:

Your `my-comp` template should look like this:

```
<div>
  <p>{{question?.title}}</p>
</div>
```

It has `?.` operator inside interpolation.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried that already but I get an error about it: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: currentQuestion? at the end of the expression [currentQuestion?] ....

Comment: please update your question with the template of `my-comp`. It's not clear how you use `currentQuestion`

Comment: Thank you. Misunderstood where the ? operator should go.